# Using Take() with bindingsource

Tags: c#, linq, take

How to use `Take()` with the following code?

```
var context = new Entities();
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();    
bi.DataSource = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to cast the result of `GetValue()` to something appropriate. Is it always going to be a sequence of some *class* type? If so, as of C# 4 and .NET 4 you could use generic covariance:

```
var context = new Entities();
var tableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();    
var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>) rawData).Take(100);
var source = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };
```

You may also want to call `ToList()` after `Take(100)`, to materialize the query results.

(This is assuming it will *be* an `IQueryable<T>`... if it's just just an `IEnumerable<T>`, cast to that instead.)

It's not clear what `Entities` is, but it's entirely possible that there's a way of getting the data out without using reflection - if you could give us more information, we could help more.

Comment: I am using an entity framework actually, the full code is as follows:    var context = new AdminEntities();
                    BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
                    var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
                    bi.DataSource = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
                    dgvLoadTable.DataSource = bi;
                    dgvLoadTable.Refresh();

Comment: @feather: No, don't post a load of code in the comments. But if you could tell us what `Entities()` inherits from, that would be helpful...

Comment: It's an entity model built using database tables

Comment: @feather: That doesn't answer my question. (I'm not an Entity Framework developer myself, but if you could tell me the base class of `Entities`, that would really help me find more information...)

Comment: I have two database, I built the entity model by using the tables of those database. The line is actually var context= new AdminEntities().Here AdminEntities is an entity model.

Comment: Again, you haven't answered the question. It's a pretty simple question: what's the base class? I'm trying to help you - *please* help me to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe I couldn't make you understand my problem. But I figured out the solution with the help of your answer. It's working now .